# Why are we allowed to make unlimited prayer in any language at a time where we are not allowed to answer amen?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, amen, personal-request-bakashot

According to (at least) [Rav Ovadiah Yosef](https://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=4310) (based on his understanding of Maran in Shulchan Aruch), one is not allowed to answer amen (except first 5 of *Kaddish*), *baruch Hu u'varuch Shemo*, or the *yimloch* response in *Kedusha*, if he is in the middle of the *Elohai Netzor* paragraph of the Amidah (i.e. after the first *Yihyu leratzon*, but before the second).

The proof comes from what Maran says in Shulchan Aruch that one should "speed up" his personal *bakashot* (that he is saying in the middle of *Elohai Netzor*, which is allowed) if he hears Kedusha or Kaddish approaching (so he can answer them properly).

This begs the question: why is he allowed to make *bakashot* and not answer amen? If *bakashot* are more important, then why does he have to speed up? If amen is more important, then why can't he say that too?

And bonus question of interest: why can't he just say amen (or any other response) as part of his *bakashot*?

Comment: I think the answer may be something along the lines of - amen is objectively "more important", but bakashot are part of tefillah and therefore not an interruption. (That would also answer your bonus question, it doesn't make sense to turn a response of amen into part of your tefillah.)

Comment: Maybe because Amen is not the kind of Bakashah that can be considered customary  (see OC 122:1 and MB ס״ק ב) to say after the Amidah, because it is not something that is expected to accur, and only happens occasionally

Comment: You could ask the same about shema koleinu.